# BitC programming language, what's your stance about it?

Tags: programming-languages

What is your opinion about [BitC](http://www.bitc-lang.org) as programming language?

Seems like a promising solution to "high level language with excellent performance that is pleasant to use" category.

What do you like and dislike about it? Do you think it has a chance to find its niche, or it is just yet another obscure programming language no one cares about.

Comment: I think this qualifies it for "nobody has heard of it": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitc